# Python Pandas Matplot Line Chart Value Error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I was trying to plot multiple line chart use same column as x axis.

My data named agg_sheet was below [image]

My code is

```
    plt.plot( agg_sheet['APPL'], agg_sheet['Std_Latency_x'])
```

but I got error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ACCMGR'
'ACCMGR' was the last value under APPL column.

Comment: Your `agg_sheet['APPL_4']` are strings so that's why you are getting this error. What kind of chart do you want to plot?  A bar chart?

Comment: Hi Bazi,   I want to use APPL as my x, and plot line chart for Std_latency and Std_latency Y

Comment: I hope you got the answer